# How can I connect coaxial cables to my wall?

Tags: walls, cabling

I have cables that my cable company laid running all over the place. How do I connect these cables to the wall?  What is the name of this part, so I know what to buy?

Comment: What do you mean "connect to the wall"? Cable TV uses coaxial cables, so something like a _coaxial wall plate_ is what would function as a wall receptacle. But it seems like your question might be more along the lines of how to wire coaxial through the walls as opposed to outside of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for "cable staples" or "cable clips" which look like this:

[image]

If you want to get fancier you can get "cord covers" which come in a lot of different styles, such as this:

[image]

Comment: nice pics.  looks good to me. +1

Comment: That last picture violates NEC 2008 400.8(6). Flexible cords and cables cannot be run through raceways. Works fine for coaxial, Ethernet, or other low voltage cables, not so good for power cords.

Comment: @Tester101 It's my understanding that would only apply if the cord is powering something considered permanently installed, such as an HVAC unit. It's pretty likely that is attached to a floor lamp and therefore not disallowed (though it's not specifically permitted, either). Would love clarification either way (maybe this deserves its own question?).

Comment: @gregmac We discussed it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9433239#9433239). I think it's not really covered by NEC, since it's not likely considered part of the electrical system.